# Why can't abstract protected methods be called from child classes?

Tags: typescript

Here is a simplified version of what I wanted in a project :

```js
abstract class Parent {
    protected abstract method(): any;
}

class Child extends Parent {
    protected method(): any {}

    protected other() {
        let a: Parent = new Child()
        a.method()
    }
}

class Other extends Parent {
    protected method(): any {}
}
```

This fails when trying to call `a.method()`. The error reads as following :

```
Property 'method' is protected and only accessible through an instance of class 'Child'.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdogN4BQC5CADlAPYS7y4AmCokM8CAtrhABY0mACgCUALlb4AngG4SAXxIkUaDAGE+AS2QtcAD3r4mGbHkIJSFKrXqMWPfoNETg0i4rIVqdBvRZ0+XChRC08rcmReVglTAkQAXgR8XAB3BA1tYREw8OAAOgcBLJzFDxV0BAB5fiCEfUNjLBw40KtvWz9uXiLnSSl3BSUgA)

From what I understand, the problem comes from the fact that `a.method()` isn't called from within the actual instance `a`. But still, it's called from within a `Child` instance, so the error seems weird. Aren't instances of the same base class "friends" with each other ?

And finally, how can I solve my issue without losing the benefits that come with `protected` ? Thanks.

Comment: because protected methods can only be called internally by the class instance or instances of classes extending the class.  in your example `a` is a new instance of `Child` separate from the instance of `Child` attempting to call it externally. if it needs to be called externally like this, then it shouldn't be a protected method. You can't restrict methods to only be callable by certain other classes as far as I know.

Comment: @bryan60 Was that meant to be that way ? In C++ and Java, if I remember well, `protected` grants access to siblings.

Comment: can't speak to java or c++ but this is the intended usage of protected in TS: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: @bryan60 The doc doesn't seem to address that point actually : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-protected

Comment: `The protected modifier acts much like the private modifier with the exception that members declared protected can also be accessed within deriving classes.` seems to cover it

Comment: Doesn't state that it has to be the same instance, it only talks about classes. In my example `this` and `a` are actually from the same deriving class, so if I take your quote literally, my example should work.

Comment: in my reading, says protected is the same as private except protected members may be accessed WITHIN deriving classes ... regardless of wording, it's what they intended and implemented. TS doesn't have a lot of features that true object oriented languages have.

Comment: @bryan60 No, because we are actually WITHIN the same deriving class. You are talking about class scopes, where the problem lies with instances.

Comment: it's a matter of semantics... to me you're not within the class if you're attempting to access a method externally from an instance.  the caller's type is irrelevant to being within or without...but semantics aside, this IS the intended and actual implementation of protected in typescript... disagree with their decision if you want, but it is the one they made.

Comment: here's a few links on the topic if you're interested in their intentions / justifications, seems like they were trying to mimic C# behavior which makes sense since they're both MS:  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10637 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8512

Comment: @bryan60 Thank you

Comment: When it comes to features that you have to ask about, be judicious in their use. Others will also have to ask about them, as will you 6 months from now. Believe me, you never forget the first time you search for and find an answer on stack overflow... and then realize you *wrote* the answer you just found.

Answer (score 3):

As per TypeScript specs if base class variable is protected we cannot use it from derived class directly on non-this object. So, you can call `this.method()`, but not `a.method()`.

Second last paragraph of page 120 of TS spec: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're getting it wrong. Whenever you do `let a: Parent = new Child();` you're *outside* the class, and that is why TS compiler is warning you. You can can call `this.method()` without issues, because this time the caller is a `Parent` instance.

```
abstract class Parent {
    protected abstract method(): any;
}

class Child extends Parent {
    protected method(): any {}

    protected other() {
        this.method(); // here
    }
}

class Other extends Parent {
    protected method(): any {}
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#)

Comment: In my example `a` and `this` are also `Parent` instances, so I don't understand why it shouldn't work the same way. The other problem is that `a` was there for a reason : in my actual projet, `Child` has a `Parent` instance as an attribute, and `method` is called on that attribute, not on `this`. So the solution you propose isn't actually a solution to my problem. The only way to make it work seems to remove `protected`, which doesn't seem to make sense.